# Hint required - Find values of $a$ and $b$ such that the limit equals $\frac{5}{12}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{ax+b}-2}{x}= \frac{5}{12}.$$

Can someone please provide me with a hint on how to approach this question?

Comment: Start with requiring limit of numerator to be zero. After that, how about L'Hospital?

Comment: Use L'Hopital an it is easy-

Comment: Two reasons why I am commenting rather than answering: [1] Posting has many defects, re [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236) [2] I am Unsure: $$12^3(ax + b) = (5x + 24)^3 \implies (12)^3 b = (24)^3 = 8 \times (12)^3 \implies b = 8.$$  However, unclear to me whether this is valid or what constraint on $a$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Can you link your expression with the definition of the derivative of a differentiable function $f$ at a point $c$?

$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(c+h) - f(c)}{h}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{ax+b}-2}{x}= \frac{5}{12}$$
An approach without using [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):

Since the denominator approaches zero as $x$ approaches zero, the numerator must also approach zero as $x$ approaches zero for the limit to be finite, i.e.,
$$\tag{1} \lim_{x\to0}\sqrt[3]{ax+b}-2=0
\implies b^\frac13 - 2 = 0$$
Now, consider the numerator:
$$\begin{align}\sqrt[3]{ax+b}-2 &= \sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{ax}{b}+1\right)b}-2 \\
&= b^{\frac13} \left(1+\frac{ax}{b}\right)^{\frac13} - 2 \\
\end{align}$$
Using the binomial approximation, i.e., $(1+x)^n \approx1+nx$ for small $x$, we get
$$ b^{\frac13}\left(1+\frac{ax}{3b}\right) - 2 = \underbrace{(b^\frac13-2)}_{0} + \frac{ax}{3b^\frac23} = \frac{ax}{3b^\frac23}$$
Thus,
$$ \tag{2} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{ax+b}-2}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{ax}{3b^{2/3}}}{x} = \frac{a}{3b^\frac23} = \frac{5}{12}$$

It is now easy to calculate $a$ and $b$ from $(1)$ and $(2)$